# Is it possible to configure a TFVCS merge tool which provides annotation (blame)?

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, version-control, merge

For a while now, I've been using WinMerge and Beyond Compare as my merge tool for Visual Studio when merging conflicts within TFS. I'd like to know if there is any tool out there (or using VS's default merge tool for that matter), that I can make use of "Annotate" to document, within the merge tool, who made which changes.

Is this possible in TFS? It seems to be par for the course functionality in Git GUI's and it would make my teams workflow much smoother.

Answer (score 0):

You can annotate a file in TFS:

1. In Source Control Explorer, go to the version of the file you want to annotate, open its shortcut menu, and then choose **Annotate**. The Annotated window displays the annotated file.

   [image]
2. On TFS Web Access, you can also annotate a file:

[image]

Comment: what I'm looking for is annotation within a merge/compare tool. So when I am doing a merge, I can see which differences to the file were changes made by me, versus as team member.

Comment: Unfortunately, you can only annotate a single file in TFS by default.